# Correct way to query rails has many through returning a nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I’m trying to figure out the “rails” way to access a collection of objects (Rails 4).

I have a team model, a member model, and a team_member model. A team can have multiple members and a member can be on multiple teams. A member can have a different status on each team.

I set up a has many through for teams and members (a team has many members through team_members)

My question is what is the correct way to query for all active team members on a team, and return a active record relation of  members

Right now I’m querying the team_member model by team_id and status id, including member. This returns a team_member relation and I access the members by team_member.member.first_name

Since once this query runs I don’t need any other info on the team_member, I’d like to get a result of members directly and deal with it as member.first_name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something between lines (not tested):

```
class Team
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :members, through: :team_members do
    def active
      where(team_members: { status: :active})
    end
  end
end

Team.last.members.active
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this

```
Team.find(2).members.where(:team_members => {:status_id =>  1})
```

Thanks